# sum of all arr[j] where i divides j

Tags: c, arrays, language-agnostic

what is best way to find just sum of all elements of array whose index divisible by i with least complexity.

I have written below code. But thats brute force. Can i get better than that

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, q;
    int mod = 1000000000 + 7;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int arr[n+1];
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n ; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    int p;
    scanf("%d", &p);
    int sum = 0;
    int j;
    for(j  = p; j <= n; j = j+p) {
        sum = (sum + arr[j]) % mod;
    } 
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to check all elements of the array, so you can't get better than O(n).

Comment: well, you've posted C code... but you can tag it "language agnostic" if you think it doesn't apply to a specific language.

Comment: Division by 1 billion while using plain int? This code is fishy, are you sure you don't get integer overflows?

Comment: @AndyTurner - You are correct about the complexity being O(n), but wrong about "_check_ **all** _elements of the array_".  See OP's code where he checks only those elements whose indices are multiples of `p`.

Comment: The posted goals do not induct the reason for `% mod`.  Post why code needs to do  `% mod`, else just drop the `%` to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

You remark that your example implementation is "brute force" and ask whether you can "do better".  Brute force usually implies an approach that is simple to implement but performs substantially more work or uses substantially more memory than is theoretically necessary.  It suggests devoting overwhelming resources in place of efficient operation.  Often, "substantially more" boils down to such approaches having higher asymptotic complexity than the best possible approaches.

Your example implementation is not like that.  Adding `n / p` arbitrary numbers requires `n / p` operations, so `O(n)` is the least asymptotic complexity an algorithm for the task can have.  That is the asymptotic complexity of your implementation, so it cannot be improved in that sense.

Furthermore, your implementation appears to perform about as few overall operations as you could hope for.  Consider this naive, alternative, ***worse*** implementation of the summation loop:

```
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if (j % p == 0) {
            sum = (sum + arr[j]) % mod;
        }
    }
```

That could be viewed as a somewhat more direct translation of the requirement into C code.  Although it's still only O(n), it might reasonably be characterized as a brute force implementation because of the (p-1)-fold excess of increments to `j` and the `n` computations of `j % p`, both of which your implementation avoids.

Bottom line: no, there is no substantially more efficient implementation than the one you present.